# Regular expression to validate characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I want to validate a text input field which has an input with four default characters, followed by minimum of 5 digits.

There is no restriction for maximum limit of numbers.

Eg: **abcd123456**

Can anyone help me with regular expression in javascript?

Comment: Instead of asking people how to write a particular regex, why don't you learn how to write any regex you need yourself? There are plenty of tutorials and online regex tools that you can use.

Answer (score 6):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
var text = document.getElementById('input').value,
    regex = /^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5,}$/;
if (!regex.test(text)) {
    alert('Not valid');
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FaYSh/

```
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    result = document.getElementById('result'), 
    regex = /^[a-z]{4}[0-9]{5,}$/;

input.onkeyup = function () {
    var text = this.value;
    if (!regex.test(text)) {
        result.innerHTML = 'Not valid';
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = 'Valid';        
    }
}
​
```

If your default characters are letters in the range `a-z` this will work.

Comment: Thanks.It works.I was trying with \d and \w in regex but it fails and also i have tried with indexOf() eventhough it works it took longer time for me.

Comment: `indexOf` is useful and usually faster than regex but sometimes you just can't escape :-)